# Count particular values in a Spark DF column combined with window functions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Sample DF:

```
var some_df = Seq(
("A", "no"),
("B", "yes"),
("B", "yes"),
("B", "no")
).toDF(
"user_id", "phone_number")
```

some_df.show()

```
+-------+------------+
|user_id|phone_number|
+-------+------------+
|      A|          no|
|      B|         yes|
|      B|         yes|
|      B|          no|
+-------+------------+
```

I am trying to count the number of "yes" for each user_id.

Code:

```
val omg_window = Window.partitionBy($"user_id")
some_df = some_df.withColumn("my_col", 
count($"phone_number"==="yes").over(omg_window)).drop("phone_number")
some_df.show()
```

My OP:

```
 +-------+------+
 |user_id|my_col|
 +-------+------+
 |      B|     3|
 |      B|     3|
 |      B|     3|
 |      A|     1|
 +-------+------+
```

Expected OP:

```
User Id .   my_col
 B .         2
 A .         0
```

Any suggestions on where I am going wrong will be highly helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are reducing the data frame, use `groupBy.agg` instead of window function; Here you compare the `phone_number` column with `yes` string (`$"phone_number" === "yes"`) and convert the result to integer which turns `true` into `1` and `false` into `0` and then we count `1`s by `sum`ing up the column:

```
some_df.groupBy("user_id").agg(
    sum(($"phone_number" === "yes").cast("integer")).as("my_col")
).show
+-------+------+
|user_id|my_col|
+-------+------+
|      B|     2|
|      A|     0|
+-------+------+
```